# When an Indicator is moved on to a chart, I want to choose the specific separate window for the installation

Tags: mql4

When using the MetaEditor for programming my indicator, I want to be able to choose which separate window my indicator will appear in and work from

Currently, I can only program either the #property indicator_chart_window or the
#property indicator_separate_window

I would like to be able to choose which separate window my new indicator would appear in by using maybe the extern or the input function.

How can this be programmed please?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectCreate(0, "TEXTTEXT", OBJ_LABEL,2, 0, 0); is the answer.
The number 2 represents the #property indicator_separate_window 2.

Comment: This will only create a chart object in the given subwindow. It won't make the indicator's plot appear in that subwindow.